# upload filename that contain special characters with curl

Tags: curl, file-upload

I need to send a request like this

```
curl -X POST --include "https://api.pixhost.to/images" \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -F 'img=@image.jpg' \
  -F 'content_type=0' \
  -F 'max_th_size=420'
```

the problem is that my image can contain special character for example image.jpg could be "a' a.jpg", but I don't know how to escape this type of filename, somebody can help me?

Very thanks

I've tried to escape "a' a.jpg" with a'\ a.jpg but doesn't work